# Drag and Dropping an Node inside javafx and accepting it

Tags: java, javafx

In my Javafx project, I want to move a Node (actually it is of Type Pane) inside the screen and make another Component accept it. For example, I have a custom Component which extends pane and I want to move it above and HBox and the HBox should accept it as a Pane and add it as one of its children.  How Can I do this?

I know some ways that interpret the dragged component as a file or text, But in this case, it is actually the component itself that need to be transfered.  I can do this by making a JSON from component and transferring the JSON as a text but I think it is not a very tidy way.

For example Consider this part of code:

```
Pane pane = new Pane();

HBox hbox = new Hbox();
```

What should I do for `OnDragDropped()` and `OnDragDetected()` methods? I want hbox accept pane as its child when pane is dragged onto hbox. (this method are Linked with fxml file and Scene Builder)